# P90x nutrition guide

Tags: muscle, nutrition, p90x

I want to start P90x, but I don't have enough time for their nutrition. I don't want to prepare anything, also I don't have access to some of the suggested foods.

I prefer to have dinner and other meals with my family. I'm very skinny and I want to add muscle, so calories should not be a big deal for me. Also, I don't have access to their `Results and recovery formula` neither. The perfect solution for me is a simple pre-workout and post-workout meal, something like a protein shake with Whey and other handy supplements, as they suggest on [the web](https://www.muscleandstrength.com/articles). I'll be thankful if someone can guide me with a simple nutrition for this workout and appreciate for my weight and goal.

I'm at level 1, 1,800 calories per day. 65 kg and about 180 cm.

Comment: P90X is not designed for someone to put on weight; **it's main goal is for overweight people to lose weight.**

Answer (score 1):

Trying to understand your question, you state that there is a nutritional plan with p90x but you don't want to follow it because:

> I don't want to prepare anything

and

> I don't have access to some of the suggested foods

So all we can really suggest (unless being a nutritionist and making you a complete plan specifically for your needs) is to:

1 - Replace any foods you have no access to with other foods of similar nutritional value.

2 - Don't be lazy. If you need to prepare meals / snacks for the day to achieve the proper nutritional / caloric intake, then do it. There are no shortcuts to a proper diet or putting on muscle.

I try and cook for 2-3 days worth of work lunches and snacks at a time and make it part of my routine / schedule to keep up with my nutritional program.

You can still eat meals with your family, but you may need to prepare some stuff individually to eat with them while they eat their food, or change your plan to accommodate the different foods you will be eating.

But most importantly, if you're going to put in the time to do the workout, you mind as well put in the time to do the nutrition side of things or you will not be getting the desired results. Diet is key in any change in physique.

Good luck with your program!

Comment: Thanks Steven, I was hoping there would be some magical Whey Formula that relieves me from any meal and nutrition plan!

Comment: There are weight gainers and protein shakes but those are called supplements for a reason! They are meant to assist your diet, not have your diet depend on them. But if you have a really hard time keeping up with your caloric needs, you can try replacing a meal / snack with a gainer shake.

Comment: Can you suggest something worthy?

Comment: You mean gainer? Well you would need to compare them according to their nutritional value versus price / budget. The majority of them are 4 scoops / ~1000 calories with about 70g protein and a variable amount of carbs and other things like creatine, BCAA's, etc. So just find a quality product within your price range / compare them at a local health food store. You can check out bodybuilding.com to compare as there are also a lot of reviews there.